# VB.NET Textbox KeyDown Event Not Firing

Tags: vb.net, events, textbox, keydown

So,

I have a textbox on a tabcontrol page, and when someone tabs out of the textbox, it is suppose to move to the next tab. This was working great before I switched the form from a UserControl to an actual Form. This change did not change actual code.

So now, I have tried everything. I have the textbox to set to AcceptTab = True, and I have KeyPreview = False (because if the form grabs the event before the textbox does, it would mess things up I am assuming).

Here is my code for the textbox:

```
 Private Sub txtMsgDTG_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtMsgDTG.KeyDown

    'check for tabbed out
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
        'If the user tabs into this field after filling out the necessary fields ...
        If txtMsgDTG.Text = String.Empty Then
            'If the user left the field BLANK ...

            'Move to next page:
            TabControl1.TabPages(0).Enabled = True
            TabControl1.TabPages(1).Enabled = True
            TabControl1.TabPages(2).Enabled = False
            TabControl1.TabPages(3).Enabled = False
            TabControl1.TabPages(4).Enabled = False
            TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1

        Else
            'If the user did NOT leave the field blank ...

            'validate message DTG
            Dim dtgCheck As String
            dtgCheck = ValidateDTG(txtMsgDTG.Text)
            If dtgCheck <> "valid" Then
                MsgBox(dtgCheck)
            Else
                'Move to next page:
                TabControl1.TabPages(0).Enabled = True
                TabControl1.TabPages(1).Enabled = True
                TabControl1.TabPages(2).Enabled = False
                TabControl1.TabPages(3).Enabled = False
                TabControl1.TabPages(4).Enabled = False
                TabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1

            End If

        End If

    End If


End Sub
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Does the event actually not fire?  If you put a breakpoint on `if e.KeyCode = ...` does it stop there?

Comment: More details on the structure would help - this is an edit box inside a tab control which is on a form?  Or is the edit box inside the tab control part of a user control which is now on a form?  Etc?

Answer (score 2):

The quick fix:

```
txtMsgDTG.Multiline = True
```

The other fix where you can keep `Multiline = False` is to subscribe to the TextBox's `PreviewKeyDown` event:

```
Private Sub txtMsgDTG_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles txtMsgDTG.PreviewKeyDown
  If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
    e.IsInputKey = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I will try it here soon, and I will confirm it.

Comment: @LoganLehman You have to supply more information.  I have a TabControl with the Textbox in TabPage1, and when I press [TAB] when in the TextBox, TabPage2 gets selected.

Comment: Oh gotcha, so instead of handling it within the KeyDown event, and I just handle it within PreviewKeyDown?

Comment: @LoganLehman I used both.  The `PreviewKeyDown` tells the TextBox to go ahead and handle the KeyDown when the Tab key is pressed.  So in my example, I added my code and still used your KeyDown event.

Comment: I am doing the same exact thing, and for some odd reason it isn't responding. The form's previewkeydown is not applied, because I don't want the form to handle it first. It works with multiline, although it cannot be multiline for its use at this moment.